# invalid operands to binary expression ('struct node ' and 'struct node ')

Tags: c, struct

I have made a header file in which I have declared a `struct node` and made an object as `List` of that struct.
Here is my header file **link.h**:

```
struct node   
{
    void *data;  //Generic data
    struct node *next;
}List;
```

**Driver.c**:

```
#include "link.h"
int main()
{   
    List list1;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to write a statement like

```
List list1; //in the driver file
```

It throws up an error saying:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('struct node' and 'struct node')
>
> use of undeclared identifier 'list1'; did you mean 'List'?

What could be causing this?

Comment: Will be happy to help... but you need to post the relevant code...

Comment: Show your code (and the exact error message).

Comment: Please provide the definition of List

Comment: I suspect you have a macro named `List` that's causing the problem.

Comment: @4386427 I edited the question. Plz have a look at it once.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your intention is to have `List` being an alias for `struct node`, so you need to use `typedef`, otherwise `List` is not a type but an instance variable of the struct.

```
typedef struct node   
{
    void *data;  //Generic data
    struct node *next;
}List;
```